# Ansible gcp_compute_instance_template: argument network is of type <class 'str'> found in 'properties -> network_interfaces'

Tags: string, dictionary, networking, google-cloud-platform, ansible

I'm currently adding GCP to our ansible system as up until now we've done the lengthy process of creating images, instance templates, groups and deploying them all manually with the CLI suite.

I'm getting stuck on an error with network interfaces trying to create a simple Instance Template using the same parameters we used to do manually.

Error:

```
    "msg": "argument network is of type <class 'str'> found in 'properties -> network_interfaces'. and we were unable to convert to dict: dictionary requested, could not parse JSON or key=value"
```

We don't have a default network for our GCP instances as we have a very specific setup so omitting the network parameter isn't viable either. When I do I get the error `The resource 'projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/global/networks/default' was not found\",`. As a test when I put the default network as my parameter I again get the `<class 'str'>` error.

I'm feel like I'm losing my mind. Here is my playbook (with parts changed for company anonymity):

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - ../vault/vault.yml
  vars:
    current_date: "{{ ansible_date_time.year }}{{ ansible_date_time.month }}{{ ansible_date_time.day }}"
    site_code: [ eur ]
    nat_zone: [ a ]
    project_name: "PROJECT_NAME"
    network_name: "STG-NET"
    image: "haproxy-master-20210219-01"

  - name: Create instance template in staging
    google.cloud.gcp_compute_instance_template:
      name: "ew2-{{ item[1] }}-ig-stg-{{ item[0] }}-haproxy-tpl-{{ current_date }}-test"
      properties:
        disks:
          - auto_delete: true
            boot: true
            initialize_params:
              source_image: "projects/{{ project_name }}/global/images/{{ image }}"
        machine_type: n1-standard-1
        network_interfaces:
          - network: 'projects/{{ project }}/global/networks/{{ network }}'
            access_configs:
            - name: access_config
              type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
      project: "{{ project_name }}"
      auth_kind: "{{ gcp_auth_kind }}"
      service_account_file: "{{ gcp_eur_service_account_file }}"
      scopes:
        - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
      state: present
    with_nested:
      - "{{ site_code }}"
      - "{{ nat_zone }}"
```

I've also tried the network param without using variables. I've tried without quotation marks. I've tried without the hyphen which is syntax incorrect and subtly changes the error to complain about a list not being a dict instead.

Any guidance as to what I'm getting wrong here would be greatly appreciated!

Environment details:

```
ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.10.5
  config file = /home/USER/ansible_aws/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/USER/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Nov 16 2020, 16:55:22) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: I have no experience with GCP and nothing to correctly test this against. Meanwhile I have some experience in reading ansible documentation and testing module usage for correct parameters (at least at pure ansible level...)

As I first did, you probably flew over the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_instance_template_module.html) and its examples a little to fast ;). Meanwhile the [specific parameter description](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_instance_template_module.html#parameter-properties/network_interfaces/network) is very clear:

> `network` - dictionary

Hence a `str` is definitely not what is expected, as explicitely reported by your error message. We get more information in the comment:

> [...] This field represents a link to a Network resource in GCP. It can be specified in two ways. First, you can place a dictionary with key `selfLink` and value of your resource's selfLink Alternatively, you can add `register: name-of-resource` to a gcp_compute_network task and then set this network field to `{{ name-of-resource }}`

If you look correctly at the [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_instance_template_module.html#examples), you'll see that they demonstrate the second scenario above (creating/registering a network to use the registered var directly in that parameter).

Taking for granted your own example in your question is using a ressource selfLink (have no clue if your current value looks correct or not...), I guess you should modify your definition as follows (abridged to network interfaces only):

```yaml
        network_interfaces:
          - network:
              selfLink: 'projects/{{ project }}/global/networks/{{ network }}'
            access_configs:
              - name: access_config
                type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

Comment: Yep. That did the job. Would be nice if the doco included any examples at all of using selfLink rather than all examples only showing creating a network first, registering it as a variable, and using that for the template creation. Many thanks for the help. Second pair of eyes does wonders!

Comment: The examples are in the collection [source code](https://github.com/ansible-collections/google.cloud/blob/d16d1e554c2259b73759b7086f820e292e7c71fd/plugins/modules/gcp_compute_instance_template.py#L515). It's fairly easy to fork, modify, and propose a PR. Meanwhile, I am not sure it's possible to have one example for every single parameter possibility in this module.